# Standalone Shell script working fine but when used is srcs of sh_binary its not working

Tags: sh, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-java

I have project structure as follows-
[PROJECT_STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZTV9.png)

Now my_shbin.sh is as below -

```
#!/bin/bash
find ../../ \( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.xml" -o -name "*.html" -o -name "*.js" -o -name "*.css" \) | grep -vE "/node_modules/|/target/|/dist/" >> temp-scan-files.txt

# scan project files for offensive terms
IFS=$'\n'
for file in $(cat temp-scan-files.txt); do
    grep -iF -f temp-scan-regex.txt $file >> its-scan-report.txt
done
```

This script works completely fine when invoked individually and gives required results.But when I add the below sh_binary in my BUILD file I do not see anything in temp-scan-files.txt file and thus nothing in its-scan-report.txt file

```
sh_binary(
    name = "findFiles",
    srcs = ["src/test/resources/my_shbin.sh"],
    data = glob(["temp-scan-files.txt", "temp-scan-regex.txt", "its-scan-report.txt"]),
)
```

I ran sh_binary from intellij using the play icon and also tried running it from terminal using bazel run :findFiles. No error is shown but I cannot see data in temp-scan-files.txt.
Any help on this issue.The documentation of bazel is very confined with approx no information whatsoever except the use case.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) And [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 1):

When a binary is run using `bazel run`, it's run from the "runfiles tree" for that binary. The runfiles tree is a directory tree that bazel creates that contains symlinks to the binary's inputs. Try putting `pwd` and `tree` at the beginning of the shell script to see what this looks like. The reason that the runfiles tree doesn't contain any of the files in `src/main` is that they're not declared as inputs to the sh_binary (e.g. using the `data` attribute). See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#run

Another thing to note is that the glob in `data = glob(["temp-scan-files.txt", "temp-scan-regex.txt", "its-scan-report.txt"]),` won't match anything, because those files are in `src/test/resources` relative to the BUILD file. However, the script tries to modify these files, and it's not typically possible to modify input files (if this sh_binary were being run as a build action, the inputs would be effectively read-only. This would work only because `bazel run` is similar to running the final binary by itself outside bazel, e.g. like `bazel build //target && bazel-bin/target`)

The most straight-forward way to do this might be something like this:

```py
genrule(
  name = "gen_report",
  srcs = [
    # This must be the first element of srcs so that
    # the regex file gets passed to the "-f" of grep in cmd below.
    "src/test/resources/temp-scan-regex.txt",
  ] + glob([
    "src/main/**/*.java",
    "src/main/**/*.xml",
    "src/main/**/*.html",
    "src/main/**/*.js",
    "src/main/**/*.css",
  ],
  exclude = [
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "**/target/**",
    "**/dist/**",
  ]),
  outs = ["its-scan-report.txt"],
  # The first element of $(SRCS) will be the regex file, passed to -f.
  cmd = "grep -iF -f $(SRCS) > $@",
)
```

`$(SRCS)` are the files in `srcs` delimited by a space, and `$@` means "the output file, if there's only one". `$(SRCS)` will contain the temp-scan-regex.txt file, which you probably don't want to include as part of the scan, but if it's the first element, then it will be the parameter to `-f`. This is maybe a bit hacky and a little fragile, but it's also kind of annoying to try to separate the file out (e.g. using grep or sed or array slicing).

Then `bazel build //project/root/myPackage:its-scan-report.txt`

Comment: I followed the above genrule approach and did bazel build :all (where my present working dir was myProject). Build was successfull but I did not see anything in its-scan-report.txt . Looks like there was some miss in cmd. Any help ??

Comment: You can use `--subcommands` to see the final command that bazel runs (you might need to do a `bazel clean` first, because --subcommands only prints what bazel actually runs, so if everything is cached, nothing will print). That should show what the glob matched. You can also put `echo $(SRCS);` in front of the grep to print out what files the glob matched. If all the expected files are found, perhaps it's something with the regexes in the regex file.